# Annotations in PDFBox 3

Tags: java, pdfbox

Updating to PDFBox 3 from 2, I get an error for the line below, and the javadoc on javadoc.io is down.  Anyone know the new way to add comments to a pdf in pdfbox 3?

```
        PDAnnotationTextMarkup txtMark = new PDAnnotationTextMarkup(PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_FREETEXT);
```

There is no property PDAnnotationTextMarkup.SUB_TYPE_FREETEXT

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This one has been replaced by `PDAnnotationFreeText`.

Comment: There is a migration guide, but that one is missing. I'll try to add it when I have more time. (Extended national holiday weekend is just over)